# How Can I Place An Image On A System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem?

Tags: .net, contextmenu, menuitem

I am using the **LEGACY** [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) because I like the look of it in Windows 7.

Does anyone know how I can place an image (without owner drawing) on a [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Or is this a limitation?

EDIT:
This is not a ContextMenuStrip - obviously that one is easy to do. Please re-read my question and look at the provided links to the actual controls.

Comment: what do you mean by _without owner drawing_? you can just browse the image.. in the design time.

Comment: @spajce This is the legacy ContextMenu control. This is NOT a ContextMenuStrip.