# How Do I Place An Image On A Legacy System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem?

Tags: .net, contextmenu, menuitem, .net-1.1

Before you think this is a duplicate. This question has nothing to do with a *ContextMenuStrip*. This question is regarding the **legacy ContextMenu** (.NET 1.1).

---

I am using the **LEGACY** [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) because I like the look of it in Windows 7.

Does anyone know how I can place an image (without owner drawing) on a [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Or is this a limitation? Maybe some API?

No, I don't want to use the ContextMenuStrip.

Comment: Original, closed thread because people thought I was talking about a ContextMenuStrip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393448/how-can-i-place-an-image-on-a-system-windows-forms-menuitem

Comment: You still have to use MenuItem.OwnerDraw, as described in the marked answer to the duplicate question.  You already knew that, it is unclear why you repeat the question.  At least describe what you don't understand about the example code shown in the MSDN article for the OwnerDraw property and post your own attempt at writing the DrawItem event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant Because, owner drawing the menu looks like garbage. I want the gradient blue rounded rectangle style in Windows 7. There's no way I have to redraw all of that in GDI+ just to place an image.